# Compile c++ with libcgicc.a using netbeans

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, netbeans, cgi

I am compiling a program with cgi libraries in a linux terminal mode. I'm using c++11. This is my compile line in Ubuntu Terminal.

> g++  -std=c++0x login.cpp /usr/lib/libcgicc.a -o login.cgi

For the time being I was working in Geany Editor to write a programs. Now I downloaded Netbeans IDE to practice . I changed the c++ version in the compiler settings in NetBeans. But I can't specify the location of libcgicc.a in the c++ compiler settings. Here with I've attached the screenshot of NetBeans c++ compiler Settings. [image]

How can I specify the libcgicc.a path in the NetBeans c++ compiler ?

Comment: I don't use this gui, but if you tick the box next to `Use Linker Libraries`, does it perhaps give you somewhere to type in extra libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add libs here

Linker --> Libraries

Browse to the `libcgicc.a` lib.

[image]